# How to upload .htaccess file using ftp

Tags: php, .htaccess, ftp

I have tried to upload .htaccess file on server, ftp gave me "critical file transfer error"
and then i renamed it to "htacces" then i uploaded, after that i was not able to rename it to ".htaccess" , it is giving me "**550 denied on server. your restricted to your account ftp**" error. so how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should contact your hosting provider about this matter. You FTP account `maybe` limited to some actions.

Answer (score 0):

try upload php-script `createhtaccess.php` with code:

```
file_put_contents('.htaccess', 'Deny from all'."\n".'Allow from all');
```

and just run him from web

or even upload `this-is-not-htaccess.txt` with .htaccess content,
then upload php script:

```
file_put_contents('.htaccess', file_get_contents('this-is-not-htaccess.txt'));
```

Comment: could you upload any *.txt file to ftp and get access to him file from web?

Comment: I didn't get that. Do you mean can I able to upload the .txt file, yes I can.